# DownloadFileCompleted being executed before the file has finished downloading

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, download, webclient

`DownloadFileCompleted` is running before the file has finished downloading resulting in files with 0 bytes and a wrong counter.

[Files with 0 bytes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfEDt.png)

```
foreach (var img in image_list)
{
    await Task.Run(() => DownloadFile(img));
}

private async Task DownloadFile(JToken file) {
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += DownloadFileCompleted(file["name"]);

        client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(file["url"]);
    }
}

private AsyncCompletedEventHandler DownloadFileCompleted(string nome) {
    total_download++;
    label1.Text = total_download;
}
```

I would like to download several files in parallel and as the file finishes downloading, a count is incremented but the count is being incremented before the download is completed (images with 0 bytes are being counted as a complete download).

Comment: Is it an option to use an [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient) instead of the `WebClient`? The `HttpClient` is fully asynchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just use `HttpClient` instead of `WebClient`, and use `async` and `await` everywhere, rather than just hacking `Task.Run` to offload the download.

```cs
static HttpClient _Client = new();
```

```cs
foreach (var img in image_list)
{
    await DownloadFile(img);
    total_download++;
    label1.Text = total_download;
}
```

```cs
private async Task DownloadFile(JToken file)
{
    using var stream = await _client.GetStreamAsync(file["url"]);
    using var fs = File.OpenWrite(file["name"]));  // or other path here
    await stream.CopyToAsync(fs);
}
```

Comment: It's bad practice to have defined `HttpClient` as `static`.

Comment: @BartłomiejStasiak You must be kidding. Besides the information on the subject available in SO, you should have found [You're using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Comment: @BartłomiejStasiak And why is that? Keeping it static means you have less chance of socket exhaustion as there is only on MessageHandler staying around.

Comment: @Charlieface Ok, I didn't read latest Microsoft recommendation (i guess it's better to read it as they are creators instead read some random articles and SO posts), but anyway I would consider to use it as singleton instead `static` object to keep consistent, DI approach and perhaps for other things, which i didn't think about of already.

Comment: Possibly DI is a little better, but that's much harder to explain in one line than just putting `static`, which at least brings the point across that you're not creating a new one each time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend multithreading approach for IO operations, since thread waits (more precisely speaking it is unnecessarily hold in app thread pool - multithreading of IO operations results in unoptimal resource usage in the end) for IO operation to complete, doing nothing in meantime.
If you want to make your current code work though, it can be fixed by adding `async` and `await`:

```cs
foreach (var img in image_list)
{
    await Task.Run(async () => await DownloadFile(img));
}

private async Task DownloadFile(JToken file) {
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += DownloadFileCompleted(file["name"]);
        await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(url), "some save location");
    }
}

private AsyncCompletedEventHandler DownloadFileCompleted(string nome) {
    total_download++;
    label1.Text = total_download;
}
```

If you want to create the most optimal solution, i recommend to get to know about `IAsyncEnumerable`, which gives you possibility of aynschronous iterating over collection.

Comment: DownloadFileAsync is void so it is not possible to use await

Comment: **`DownloadFileTaskAsync()`**. `DownloadFileAsync()` is event-driven, non awaitable. You should probably suggest to move to HttpClient

Comment: Yes, i edited my answer, considering your hints about `DownloadFileAsync(...)`, being `void`. I also agree it would be better to use `HttpClient` as it's modern and easier to use : )